# Having two modules on x-axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-powerbi

I have a column chart on power bi with option OI against each strike and for each strike for all of the dates. So in short it has two layer in x-axis 1<sup>st</sup> layer is strike and 2<sup>nd</sup> layer is date.

For all the strikes in the table there are subgroup for all dates in the tables on x-axis. And y-axis is OI so I have bars with value of OI for each date for each strike. The problem is the chart is too long and I have to scroll so many times to see the full chart as there are so many strikes. I want it to be condensed to show the whole chart in one page. But I can't find a way. I tried tableau but it doesn't deliver good visual of the chart.

I was hoping if it can be done in excel but I couldn't find a way to add two layers into the x-axis. I'm hoping anyone here might know how to do it in Excel. Or some other way...

The chart in power bi:

[image: the chart in power bi]

Please help